# What is the best way for multiple teams working on same tasks

Tags: jira, agile

I'm using JIRA agile and create a scrum board for a project. This project have multiple teams which are back-end, iOS and Android. For most of tasks, iOS and Android will be the same because eventually they will have same features but in different platforms.

One way is to create one task for both iOS and Android. For example, Creating a Login Window. And we can create two sub-tasks for it. Now I have two question about this way:

1. Estimation: Assume the estimation of this task on iOS is 3 and on Android is 3 as well. Do I accumulate them and set 6 for this task or just keep it 3?
2. What if one team finishes this task but another team doesn't, so this task will continue on the following sprint but only one team involved, Do I need to adjust the estimation or just keep the same? If keep the same, the total estimation will become inaccurate.

Another way is to have separate tasks. Using labels or prefixes to distinguish them. This approach won't have estimation issues but hard to check if one feature is implemented on both two platforms or only one.

So which way should I go? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about team workflow (try http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: or per the [agile] tag, try the Project Management site at http://pm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to create separate tasks. Android and iOS actually share a lot of the same fundamentals, but there's always catches and gotchas. There's also different rules and release schedules. For example, our iOS release schedule was often one week before Android due to having to deal with Apple app submission, while Google's app submission was often done within 10 minutes

Both platforms are using different programming languages, and despite what ANYONE tells you, both teams will have different amounts of experience, even if it's one facet of development. Also, both platforms will have different things built into them that can cut down the development time, and have a different set of communities to help them with different parts.

Example: Your iOS team may do the UI in 4 hours, but your Android team is having problems because they are having to adapt an iOS mockup to Android and is given 0 flexibility on the matter (happens too often).

Comment: Great one. Make sense.